# OneDrive for Windows 10 - Remove logged out account

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I'm using the [new OneDrive version](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-in-Windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) (unified for both personal and business account) and I configured two accounts on it:

1. My personal account (the same I log in on Windows)
2. My business account

Some months ago I left my previous company and I have no more access to the second account (the business one) and every time I login on Windows 10 I receive a message saying that username or password are wrong.

It's quite annoying and I would like to remove this account, but I can't since there is no "unlink" button on the settings window of OneDrive (probably because it's stuck at the login phase).

[image]

What could I do? Is there any "manual" trick (e.g. removing the account from a configuration file or the Windows register)?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to click on "unlink this PC" on the account tab within the OneDrive Settings.

Comment: There are [tutorials](https://www.clouddirect.net/resources/sharepoint-sites-how-to-unlink-a-onedrive-for-business-account/) out there, but it sounds like you would need to authenticate with your business account credentials to remove it.

Comment: @Run5k I can't unfortunately, they deactivated my account few days after I left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove lost business account from registry:

```
 HKCU\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\(businessUwant2remove)
```

and re-login

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but could you please cite your source?

Comment: @Run5k Shy to say that, but trial and error method. At least it worked in the beginning of 2016 when one of my client came with the same problem. I appreciate if OP confirm that it still works since attempt to contact M$ regarding this didn't gave any answer on this subject

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot for the solution man! I would like to vote your answer as useful too, but unfortunately I have not enough reputation! Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! I glad it still works, that what is  important